# how to get textbox value on click of checkbox

Tags: jquery, .net

I have gridview row checkbox. and related that checkboxes there are also textboxs. If i click on any checkbox than value of related textboxs should be  sum.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="50" ItemStyle-Height="50">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" ToolTip='<%# Eval("id_form") %>' runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>--%>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value1">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtvalue1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="80" Text='<%#Eval("Value1") %>' CssClass="fro-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value2">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtvalue2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="80" Text='<%#Eval("Value2") %>' CssClass="fro-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value3">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtvalue3" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="80" Text='<%#Eval("Value3") %>' CssClass="fro-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value4">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtvalue4" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="80" Text='<%#Eval("Value4") %>' CssClass="fro-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

When I click on checkbox id with **checkAll**, then below jquery code should run. And related that checkboxes there are also textboxs. If i click on any checkbox than value of related textboxs should be sum.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      Calculation();
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
      alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
  });
});

function Calculation() {
  var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID%>");
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
    var txtvalue1 = $("input[id*=txtvalue1]")
    if (txtvalue1[i].value != '') {

      alert(txtvalue1[i].value);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

when i click checkbox than it gives the value of all the textboxs. but need only checkbox checked value and than checked value should be sum.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .is(':checked') method instead of .prop('checked') method. The former is the generally best accepted approach for determining the "checked" state of a checkbox.